# IE 8.0 show script error

Tags: javascript

I am getting a **script error** in **IE 8.0** but not getting in Mozilla. put suggest how to fix that.  below is my web Page:

```
        <%@ page contentType="text/html" %>
        <%@ page session="false" %> 

        <% taglib prefix="page" uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/page"%>

        <% taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jso/jstl/core"%>
       <head>
       <title>my Page</title>
        </head>
        </body>
       <c:set var="pageName" value="about" scope="request"/>
       <page:apply-decorator name="headerContent" page="/WEB-INF/jsp/myDetails"/>
       </body>
       </html>
```

the message it shows--> HTML Parsing Error : Unable to modmify the parent container element before the child element closed. myDetails.html,   **line:0 char:0**

Comment: Fixing your first body tag so that it's `<body>` would be a good place to start.

Comment: Also, it's better to provide resulting html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your markup inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<html>
   <head>   
      <%@ page contentType="text/html" %>
      <%@ page session="false" %> 
      <% taglib prefix="page" uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/page"%>
      <% taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jso/jstl/core"%>
      <title>my Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <c:set var="pageName" value="about" scope="request"/>
       <page:apply-decorator name="headerContent" page="/WEB-INF/jsp/myDetails"/>
    </body>
</html>
```